# Xcode 6.1.1 does not support iOS 8.3 on 11/4/2015

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

Is there anyway round to this. 
I have updated both Xcode as wel as iPhone today.
this created problem as both does not support each other.
Is there anything I could do?

Answer (score 1):

Just checked xcode update.
installed 6.3 version